# Transaction's initial node

Tags: nodes

Initially, transaction is created in some local node and is in its local pool. Then it propogates to other nodes.
So, is it possible to know, what node was transaction initially created by?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. There is no data pertaining to the origin node sent with the tx. The best you could do is connect to *all* the ethereum nodes and assume the first to send you a tx is the origin, which still wouldn't be accurate because they may have just gotten it from another node before the other node sent it to you.

Furthermore, there isn't really a concept of an "origin node". I can send the tx from my laptop (which isn't running a node) to 10 different nodes. Then there is no "origin" node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about it, but if you are dealing with a private-net this should get you the desired result. You can get block number of any transaction using *eth.getTransaction* and then miner of that block using *eth.getBlock* (*eth.getBlock(eth.getTransaction("TxnHash").blockNumber).miner* ) and then you can check which node holds the account shown as miner.

Comment: Thx. But this way i'll find a miner of transaction. And I need to know node's info, that initially sent the tx to the network